# how to make terminal prompt messages?

Tags: c++, linux

I have a image processing project in C++ using opencv. The program runs correctly and I get the desired output. However, I have some messages that I print out using the cout command. When I run the program using the terminal (./myprogram) the messages are displayed correctly. When I double click the executable file I get only the output (in my case a new video is created) But I do get the messages. How do I get the program to automatically prompt the messages when it is not run from the terminal.
PS: I use ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a script like this, lets call it  run.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd work_dir
./myProgram
read -r -p "Press any key..." key
```

Then do:

```
xterm -e run.sh
```

and make your desktop shortcut run this command instead of the program directly.